# APS restore toolbar after MarkupsCore extension enterEditMode

Tags: autodesk-forge

In Autodesk Platform Services, MarkupsCore extension, enterEditMode hides the viewer toolbar. I was expecting that after calling leaveEditMode() the viewer toolbar to be restored. But it does not.

How to reenable toolbar after finishing editing markups?

1. Entering Edit Mode:

```
NOP_VIEWER.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore').then((ext)=>{
     markup=ext;
     markup.enterEditMode();
});
```

2. Leaving Edit Mode:

```
markup.leaveEditMode();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add in the end

> markup.hide()